# @Timed annotation does not work with request scoped beans?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-aop, prometheus, spring-micrometer, requestscope

I have a bean that has a request scope and in it there is a method that is annotated with micrometer(io.micrometer.core.annotation)  @Timed but it is not showing in the metrics.  It shows if the bean is in the default scope (Singleton).

```
@RequestScope
@Component
public class MyTask {
 //some local variables here
public MyTask() {
  //some unhelpful stuff
}
    @Timed(value = "mappingTask")
    @Override
    public void map(List<MyPojo> myApps) {
      //Some process
}

}
```

Is it not supposed to work with Request scope or what am I missing.

Answer (score 0):

taken from: [Micrometer github issues](https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/micrometer/issues/361)

The original issue/question:

> @Timed put on a method of an arbitrary Spring-managed bean is silently
>   ignored.

And this was the response from Micrometer:

> The TimedAspect aspect now exists in micrometer-core, but will not be
>   autoconfigured in Spring Boot 2 or micrometer-spring-legacy. We can
>   revisit application of @Timed via AOP or a BPP in Boot 2.1, depending
>   on how the community reacts to the feature.
>
> To configure manually:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
public class AutoTimingConfiguration {
   @Bean
   public TimedAspect timedAspect(MeterRegistry registry) {
      return new TimedAspect(registry);
   }
}
```

im not sure this is your issue, but could be worth a try.

Comment: I tried this but it did not work.  I believe the issue is with the timing the **@Timed** annotation is weaved in case of  **@RequestScope** annotated beans.  As I said, it all works if the bean has the default scope.(Singleton)

Comment: Aspectj is compile time weaving, while Spring AOP is proxy bean (runtime) weaving. Well sorry cant help you then

Comment: Thomas, a little correction: AspectJ _can be_ used via compile-time weaving, but inside Spring is usually used via load-time weaving. The latter is also the documented way in the Spring manual. @dawit, your problem is still unsolved. Maybe you want to consider posting a real [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which would allow others to more than just guess. Give us something we can run and analyse. I am quite sure you will get a helpful answer that way.